# use gmail or live service to login in the website but limit only one user (admin) to login

Tags: asp.net

I’ve a Gmail account, assume that me@gmail.com. Now I want to login (as admin) in my website through this account. I know I can use OpenID etc. for that purpose but I want to limit it for just me only. Can I do this? I don’t let anyone else to know which service I used to login and what is my address and etc. (Note: My website contains just one and only one login form, for just me, only!)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that once your OpenID has been verified you will have you own database storing logins (me@gmail.com) so you provide persistence.

You would have a table of logins with an admin column so that for example even though noadmin@gmail.com was verified by OpenID I do not want to let them access, so `Response.Redirect` them outta there.